# Android/java draw() -specifically isRecycled() -throwing null pointer exception?

Tags: java, android, animation, bitmap, draw

I am beginning to learn animation in Java for android, and for the life of my I cant figure out why this is throwing  a null pointer exception Can anyone help?

The program is simple. it starts up, upon pressing the "startGame "button user is proptedd to choose an avatar. the avatar then passes the type of graphic that will be used in the game. why is is throwing null?
do I have to pass on the avatar variable thrugh an intent? if so why

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int avatar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClickStartGame(View view) {
    choosePlayer();
}

private void startGame() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

private void choosePlayer() {
    AlertDialog choose =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    choose.setTitle("Choose Your Avatar...");
    choose.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
            "Iggy",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    avatar =  R.drawable.ship;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    startGame();
                }
            });

    choose.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
            "DeuCe",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    avatar =  R.drawable.impala_ship;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    startGame();
                }
            });
                    choose.show();
}

public int getAvatar() {return avatar;}
}

//then...

public class GameActivity extends Activity {
private TDView gameView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new TDView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gameView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    gameView.resume();
}
}

//then....
public class TDView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
volatile boolean playing;
Thread gameThread = null;
private PlayerShip player;
private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private SurfaceHolder ourHolder;



public TDView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ourHolder = getHolder();
    paint = new Paint();
    player = new PlayerShip(context);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (playing) {
        update();
        draw();
        control();
    }
}

private void update(){ player.update();}

private void draw() {
    if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
        canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,0));

        canvas.drawBitmap(player.getBitmap(), getX(), getY(), paint);

        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

private void control() {}
public void pause(){
    playing = false;
    try{
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void resume(){
    playing = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
}

//then finally....

public class PlayerShip {
private Bitmap bitmap;
private int x, y;
private int speed = 0;
MainActivity shipType;


public PlayerShip(Context context) {
    x = 50;
    y = 50;
    speed = 1;
    setBitmap(context);
}

public void update() { x++; }
public int getX() { return x; }
public int getY() { return y; }
public int speed() { return speed; }
public Bitmap getBitmap() { return bitmap; }

public void setBitmap(Context context) {
    shipType = new MainActivity();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            shipType.getAvatar());
}
}
stackTrace...
05-09 10:18:02.502 31920-429/com.ff.deuceinspace E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4758
Process: com.ff.deuceinspace, PID: 31920
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1269)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1325)
    at com.ff.deuceinspace.TDView.draw(TDView.java:43)
    at com.ff.deuceinspace.TDView.run(TDView.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)




//dont worry about the import statements
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace so we can see where the nullpointer is.

Comment: sorry the nullPointerException is in the setBitmap() in the PlayerShip class.
specifically it is on shipType.getAvatar()